# Get last commit which leads to a merge

Tags: git

I have two branches (`development` and `main`). From time to time the development branch gets merged into the main branch.
So there are merge commits like `Merge branch 'development' into 'main'`.

Now I do need the commit hash from the last **development commit**, which **leads** to the merge commit - not the merge commit itself, which is on the master branch. Is that possible?

Doing something like `git log --merges origin/master --oneline --grep='^Merge branch development into main' -1` gives me the merge commit on the master branch, but I need the commit **before** this one (on the development branch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the merge commit, you can do a:

```
git log <mergeCommit>^2 -1
```

That would give you the last development commit leading to that merge.
It uses the [`git rev-parse` `<rev>^[<n>]` notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em)

In a bash session

```
git log -1 \
 $(git log --merges origin/master --format=format:%H --grep='^Merge branch development into main' -1)^2
```

Comment: So I have to use two commands, right? First get the merge commit, then get the development commit.

Comment: @user3142695 In a bash session, you should be able to use one command. I have edited the answer to propose one (not tested)